# Cannot insert very long text in long text field

Tags: 7, entities, database

When I insert a very long text in a long text field, Drupal shows this error:

> Data too long

This field is allocated for articles in a content type, so I am sure the data will not be longer than some extent, but when the number of characters is almost more than 30000, it shows the error. Is there any default limitation on it?

The exception I get is the following one:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1406 Data too long for column `'source'` at row 1: `INSERT INTO {locales_source} (location, version, source, context, textgroup) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum [theoretical data length in this database column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) is 4'294'967'299 characters (less than 2<sup>32</sup>)

It is also [limited by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html):

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type, but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers.

"Data too long" is a MySQL error message, not Drupal one, so you need to re-configure your MySQL if you want to allow longer texts in body (or any other field)., as described [in MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).

Comment: Yes you are right, this is an error from MySQL not drupal. I updated the question, does it give you any clue ?

Comment: @Mohammad it only confirms my answer is valid. You need to re-configure your MySQL sever. Questions about server configuration are best to ask at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), but be sure to read MySQL docs I linked in my answer first, and try configuration options pointed in them.

Comment: then what exactly do I need to configure?

Comment: @Mohammad read the docs I linked, please. Search for the quote I pasted, and read on. Then, if you can't do it, go to dba.stackexchange.com or servefault.com